# Looking for Attractive Forum to Add to My Application

Tags: plugins, user-forums

Looking for an attractive, highly customizable forum plugin to implement. Don't want to build one myself, but don't want to settle for usual crap. Something Ajax-y?

Was leaning towards Community Server but would love to see what others had to reccomend.

Thanks.

EDIT: This is an ASP.NET/C#/SQL application

Comment: licence?copyright, copyleft . . ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://ask.metafilter.com/52003/Good-community-forum-software

Options

- [Lussumo's Vanilla](http://getvanilla.com/)
- [Simple Machines](http://www.simplemachines.org/)
- [BBPress](http://bbpress.org/)

Attractive is subjective, so you'll need to look around.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't already have authentication or anything running, you might check out [Active Forums](http://www.activemodules.com/products/activeforums.aspx) that runs within DotNetNuke.  I've been using it and I'm very happy thus far, ajax paging for users, standard paging for bots, social bookmarking built in, and many other nice items.

Answer (score 0):

YetAnotherForum is ASP.NET/C#/SQL like your application and it looks very nice. I'm not sure about AJAX though.

It can run in DotNetNuke, Rainbow, or stand-alone.

http://www.yetanotherforum.net/features.aspx